# Can’t find my user on the external hard drive

Tags: dell-inspiron

I had problems with my Dell laptop.

After asking some experts they told me to replace the hard drive with a SSD drive. They then converted this hard drive to an external hard drive,when I connect the hard drive to my laptop, I can’t find my user which had all my photos stored on folders in the desktop. What could be the problem?

As far as I understood, nothing was deleted from the hard drive, they only took it off and replaced it with the SSD.

Comment: Un-hide hidden folders in folder options, now you should be able to see your old users folder.

Comment: Do you not see the “Users” (probably localized in your language) folder? Do you see the “Windows” folder?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the photos (and like documents) are in your secured USERS folder on the Hard Drive.

Reinstall the Hard Drive temporarily, start up, and put the photos and other documents in C:\Temp on the hard drive. Shut down, remove the hard drive and try again. You should be able to retrieve from C:\Temp.

I have done this numerous times.

Comment: Thank you,I’ll try doing this.

Comment: No need to re-install the drive. The data is accessible either way.

Comment: The userid has its own unique identifier, so trying to access the user folder from a "different" user normally does not work (certainly for me)

Comment: That’s correct. Explorer will ask you to grant access. And even if it doesn’t, you can do so manually.